# Read from a database view rather than a table using SQL

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to read data from a view that I have created based on other views in my database using Python.

Database set-up:

```
Redshift-postgres
  dev
    Schemas
      schema_name
        Tables
          table_name
        Views
          view_name
```

Python code:

```
connection=psycopg2.connect("dbname=dev host=redshift.amazonaws.com port=5439 user=user password=password")

cursor = connection.cursor()
schema = "SELECT count(*) FROM schema_name.table_name;"
schema2 = "SELECT count(*) FROM schema_name.view_name;"
result = pd.read_sql(schema, connection)
```

When I run the code with `schema` it returns data from a table but when I try to run `schema2` it does not return anything and no error message is provided. The script does not stop it just idles.

Am I doing something wrong when trying to get data from a view rather than a table?

**UPDATE**

When I run `schema2 = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;"` it does return the following:

```
table_catalog    table_schema   table_name  table_type 
dev              schema_name    view_name         VIEW
```

It lists the view I am trying to read data from.

I created the view like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema_name.view_name
AS SELECT *
        CASE
            WHEN statement
            ELSE false
        END AS column_name, 

   FROM schema_name.another_view_name
   LEFT JOIN schema_name.another_view_name_2 data_1 ON data_2 = data_3
   LEFT JOIN schema_name.another_view_name_3 data_4 ON data_5 = data_6
```

I have named irelevant data `data_x` where I join the views based on some conditions.

Comment: It doesn't return an integer value, like 0?

Comment: `schema` returns `0 100`, the index `0` and the number of rows `100`. `schema2` does not return anything. I am running this script in the terminal and after I run the script `python3 my_script.py` it just idles.

Comment: Are you sure that the view is supposed to return rows? I mean do you know the create query for that view? can you try with psql first to see what the view returns as result?

Comment: I wrote the view, I understand that view holds rows, what other type of information could it hold? It's just a `SELECT` placed in a `VIEW`, isn't it? Or I can't retrieve any information from a view that is created as a `SELECT`? I will add simplified `view_name` code in the original question.

Comment: Does it return a value if you run the actual query that is used to create the view (without the `CREATE VIEW`) part? If so, what happens if you wrap it in a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that amazon redshift DB got clogged up and had 5 queries that ran for 4 days with no response. Anyhow, I still find that reading from a view with 2 left joins takes like 3 hours to read which is not how it should work. The view has only 1.2m rows. Thank you for your suggestions.